# Symfony set path to web folder

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I need run cron task `/www/mydomain.com/lib/task/geoCronTask.class.php` from url which is outside public folder:

```
/www/mydomain.com/web
```

I can set the domain to point to a folder : `/www/mydomain.com/` but don't know how to configure in symfony.

Comment: You should not do that. Just create an action that calls your sf task, as per example using PHP [exec](http://php.net/exec).

Comment: Unfortunately this command is blocked for security reasons.

Comment: Have a look at [ybRunTaskPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/ybRunTaskPlugin)